# Can't render my component, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I written my code following a udemy course. I'm unable to render the Layout component's content is there anything I missed or any syntax mistakes that needs to be corrected to sort this out ?

```
const Aux = (props) => {props.children}

export default Aux;

import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';

class App extends Component
 {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <p>Hai.. Is this working ? </p>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxx';

const layout = (props) =>(
    <Aux>
    <div>Toolbar,Sidebar,Backdrop</div>
    <main>
        {props.children}
    </main>
    </Aux>
    
);

export default layout;
```

Comment: I see no issue with this code, it runs & renders in a codesandbox I copy/pasted it into (had to mock the `Aux` component though). Can you share the exact error message and stacktrace?

Comment: Oops, completely missed the `Aux` definition in your snippet. Yes, you've a typo type issue, you need to return `props.children`, i.e. either `const Aux = (props) => { return props.children};` or `const Aux = (props) => props.children;`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that `Aux` is a blank component.

When you use the syntax `const Aux = (props) => {props.children}` you actually return  nothing!

You see, javascript thinks that `{ }` is the function itself and not return your `props.children`. Just remove the brackets:

```
const Aux = (props) => props.children;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code as below:

```
const Aux = (props) => props.children // removed the {} so that it can return the children 

export default Aux;

import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';

class App extends Component
 {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout>
          <p>Hai.. Is this working ? </p>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxx';

const Layout = (props) =>( //changed the layout to Layout: it needs to be capitalized
    <Aux>
    <div>Toolbar,Sidebar,Backdrop</div>
    <main>
        {props.children}
    </main>
    </Aux>
    
);

export default layout;
```